# Mask Video Into Shape and Compose Over Another Video (AVComposition)

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the capabilities of `AVComposition`, but I have a task that I am failing to know how to approach.

I have a background video, which is a video of a tree;

[image]

I also have a foreground video, which is a video of a horse;

[image]

I have a transparent .png mask, which is a circle (shown with background for clarity).

[image]

My ideal goal is to create a H.264 video, save to the user's device, that shows the tree in the background, with the horse video masked into a circle.

While I believe using `init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)` to apply a `CIBlendWithMask` filter could be feasible, I have no idea how I would render the "masked" video (since it would be transparent around the circle) over the background video.

Comment: I guess such question needs a bounty

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: it's a suggestion for encouragement , you're free